# How to completely change RecyclerView Contents

Tags: android

I am using a `DatePicker Dialog` on the basis of which I am populating a `recyclerView`.

I am successful in fetching data to `recyclerview`, but the new data received is shown below the default data, how can I completely remove the Old Data with the Newly received data.

Here is my code:

```
progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.spin_kit);
    Sprite cubeGrid = new CubeGrid();
    progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(cubeGrid);
    Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    myModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int date = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                    textView.setText(String.valueOf(year));
                }
            }, year, month, date);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });

    textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            loadFunction();
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
}
private void loadFunction() {
    URL = "https://calendarific.com/api/v2/holidays?api_key=7b30b25a8d7fe05f34eddfb3d3e9a033828778eb&country=IN&year=" + textView.getText().toString();
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e("Response : ", response);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONObject responseObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response");
                JSONArray jsonArray = responseObject.getJSONArray("holidays");
                Log.e("sdsd", String.valueOf(jsonArray));
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject dateJson = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("date");
                    String iso = dateJson.getString("iso");
                    MyModel myModel = new MyModel(jsonObject1.getString("name"), jsonObject1.getString("description"), dateJson.getString("iso"));
                    myModelList.add(myModel);
                }
                MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), myModelList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                               }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                     }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

So, what I am basically asking is how to refresh the new data with old one and if is it the right way to get the changed `TEXTVIEW`'s text?

Comment: No need for all caps at the end there. We get what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Before adding objects to myModelList, clear all data. That way you'll always have the newest data in the adapter.

Comment: how ? can u please explain more